# how to handle parse error for eval function in php

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error

I'm trying to use the eval function for php.
but I'm stuck in handling the parse error.
like considering if I have edge cases like 1.. or 1++
if gives me parse error:syntax error, .....

anyone knows how to handle syntax error or how to bypass the error message?
I want to give a better error message.

also is it possible to store the error message to a variable?

TIA

Comment: Why the hell do you use `eval` on code that was apparently not written by you?

Comment: There has to be a better way than using eval on server side, or even client side for that matter...

Comment: well, this is the project specs, and wont be used for real-world purposes.

Comment: When someone provides a elaborate answer (which is correct) you should do your tiny duty and accept it.

Answer (score 20):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

> As of PHP 7, if there is a parse error in the evaluated code, `eval()` throws a `ParseError` exception. Before PHP 7, in this case `eval()` returned `FALSE` and execution of the following code continued normally. It is not possible to catch a parse error in `eval()` using `set_error_handler()`.

Instead use this:

```
<?php

try {
    eval('will cause error');
} catch (ParseError $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/1giOS

Comment: This should be the new selected answer

Comment: I tried to catch these errors with the usual generic "Exception $e"
This one works.

Answer (score 12):

```
$response = @eval($string);
if (error_get_last()){
    echo 'Show your custom error message';
    //Or you can 
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

Comment: Only after like 30 minutes of trying to track it down did I find this and it actually helped me catch the error. In my defense, this wasn't my code. I was fixing someone else's and they used eval like it was going out of style!

Comment: `error_get_last()` does not really work like this. In fact, it returns null only if there is absolutely no error in all the script, even outside the eval'd string. You can overwrite the last error by causing one yourself, like `@trigger_error('MY_LAST_ERROR');`, and later check if the message in the array returned by `error_get_last` is `'MY_LAST_ERROR'`, but this only works if the currently `set_error_handler` returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

> If there is a parse error in the evaluated code, `eval()` returns `FALSE` and execution of the following code continues normally. It is not possible to catch a parse error in `eval()` using `set_error_handler()`.

But as you won't be calling `eval` on arbitrary code (right?), this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: yes, I used preg_match to validate it. is there any way to change the error message though?

Comment: @ordinaryman09: You can't use `preg_match` to validate arbitrary PHP code (AFAIK).  The fact that you have "edge cases" demonstrates that.

Comment: yes, it's not perfect, so I need to handle the edge cases just by displaying the proper error message.

Comment: @ordinaryman09: This is very dangerous.  The fact that your validation isn't perfect means that you can potentially execute arbitrary PHP code.  You need to find a better solution than using `eval`.  But anyway, if you browse through the comments on the manual page I linked to, someone came up with a "solution", which is using `fork` before running `eval`.  I don't know whether it works, though.