# Getting parse error, syntax error when i am using eval()

Tags: php

```
eval("\$flag = $expression;");
```

if the `$expression` is not correct its throwing parse error, how to catch it.

Its causing performance issue .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to handle parse error for eval function in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085284/how-to-handle-parse-error-for-eval-function-in-php)

Comment: https://eval.in/655336 (using try catch)

Comment: you can check this too:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223899/php-eval-and-capturing-errors-as-much-as-possible